# Confusion in notation and terminology; Multiplicative group; Reduced norm;Source :Topics in Galois theory Serre

Tags: algebraic-geometry, notation, terminology

[image]

I was trying to read the above section from the book, I am lost. I am confused with notation and terminology.

I understand till here "..... is a group of type $(2,2)$".

Now I am confused with notation. I read on wikipedia that $G_{m}$ denotes the multiplicative group of the field. I am confused as $H^{*}$ is also the multiplicative group of standard field of quaternion. Why use two notation for multiplicative group of standard field of quaternions.

What is this map, denoted by $N$. He says It is the reduced norm.

**Edits (Following the comments):** [image]

Comment: You have been asking 6 questions in less than 24 hours about Serre's book. Don't you think that you should take a large breath, maybe a little rest, and keep questioning for things that are resisting after hours or even days of thought about them? Not just asking because, on the first lecture, you have not understood...

Comment: @JeanMarie I am reading on my own(self-study). I had these doubts for last 3-4 days. These are doubts about notation and terminology used in book.

Comment: @JeanMarie 4 out of my last 6 question were about reference request and notation /terminology. I spent last few days thinking about what these notation might mean, I did google search, but nothing helped.

Comment: All right, I understand. I know self study is not easy. But I don't understand why you meet so much difficulty with notations: in the vast majority of books, the author has special pages devoted to the notations used in the book.

Comment: @JeanMarie See the image (I have edited the question ). I understand that It is not a undergraduate level book . He assumes a lot.

Comment: Never seen a so meager Notation page. He gives evident notations but omits all the other ones...

Answer (score 1):

Here are my best guesses:

1) I think the phrase a group "of type $(2,2)$" just means that the (finitely generated abelian) group's invariant factors are $2,2$, i.e.,
$$
D = \frac{Q_8}{\{\pm 1\}} \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{2\mathbb{Z}} \times \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{2\mathbb{Z}} \, .
$$
Darmon/Serre uses this notation on p. xiv of the Intro, p. 13, and again on p. 16, and it seems consistent with this interpretation.

2) The reduced norm of a quaternion $\alpha = t + xi + yj + zk$ is
\begin{align*}
N(\alpha) &= (t + xi + yj + zk)\overline{(t + xi + yj + zk)} = (t + xi + yj + zk)(t - xi - yj - zk)\\
&= t^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2
\end{align*}
where $\overline{{}\cdot{}}$ denotes conjugation, similar to that for complex numbers.  (See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_algebra#Structure) for the definition of reduced norm for a general quaternion algebra.)

3) I think $\mathbb{G}_m$ means $\mathbb{G}_m(\mathbb{Q}) = \mathbb{Q}^\times$, that is, the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{Q}$, not $\mathbb{H}$.  One can show (again, just like for complex numbers) that a quaternion is a unit iff its norm is nonzero.  So the first component of the map $(N, \phi): \mathbb{H}^\times \to \mathbb{G}_m \times \text{SO}_3$ is just the norm map, which takes
\begin{align*}
N: \mathbb{H}^\times &\to \mathbb{G}_m = \mathbb{Q}^\times\\
t + xi + yj + zk &\mapsto t^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \, .
\end{align*}

(For those curious, the notes referenced in the OP can be found [here](http://www.ms.uky.edu/~sohum/ma561/notes/workspace/books/serre_galois_theory.pdf).)

Comment: It make sense. Thanks a lot